# Trying to host a laravel 5.7 app in AWS EC2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So...i'm pretty new in hosting websites and horst yet with hosting in cloud services. I'm having a pretty bad time trying to host a Laravel 5.7 application in AWS and i really need some help/direction.

My situation is like this:

- I have a normal Laravel 5.7 app that uses MySQL database and Laravel Queue(database type).
- I need a process to constantly listen/monitor the job queue and execute them.

The thing is, i just lerned that you can't use normal hosting to do this(listen the job queue) and that i need a VPS service.
In my searches i saw that AWS have a 1 year free trial and i thought it was worth to take a look. The thing is, i started from EC2 and got as far as installing apache, mysql, php, git, etc. I made a clone of my project to the `/etc/www/html` and install composer dependencies... but i'm not quite understaing what to do for the app run, and in looking for tutorials everything is always differet and nothing ever works. I dont know what else to do, this is my first contact with cloud services.

That said, my question is what can i do to host my Laravel 5.7 app in amazon, and is it really the better solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently doing what you're trying to do.  The configuration is outlined [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration).  You will need to install supervisord.  You didn't leave enough information about what type of instance you're running, so I can't get you more complete instructions, but if you follow these steps, your queue should run as expected.

Comment: thanks, @Michael. 
I'm trying to host it in a EC2 ubuntu server, but i'm having a really bad time, i cant even start the app. I'm following some tutorials but nothing works the same as the tutorial and everything goes wrong. Do you have any recomendations that can help me with it ?

Comment: Hey @Wally, I'd be happy to continue to help you...  With regard to recommendations, the flow I generally use is to do as you did, follow the tutorials.  Posting on here is great for when you get stuck, but I usually follow the error trails I get in my apps first...  When you say you can't "start" the application, how are you trying to "start" it?  Are you using PHP's built in web server (which I would never suggest)?  Are you using Nginx?  Apache?  Are all of your dependencies installed and set up?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thanks for you help. So, i installed everything (Apache2, MySQL and Composer), the problem i'm having is in to make apache run the laravel app. Some of the things i tried are: i copied my roject folder to /var/www/html directory and followed steps #9 to #11 of this tutorial: sudo chown -R -v ubuntu /var/www/html. Sometimes, when i access the addres of my server, i can "see" the project folder and its contents, but not the application running. Apache inst even running now.

Comment: Let's see you're Apache configuration.